# How to add spaces dropdownlist values in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist in a view like this,

```
<style type="text/css">
.form-control {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FileName, ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Items"]), new { size = 15, @class = "form-control" , @style = "padding: 10px;"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FileName)
```

The values look like below,

```
aaa.txt (2015-01-01) (0 B)
abcdedfff.txt (2015-02-01) (17 MB)
```

I want to add some spaces between these items so that it would look like below,

```
aaa.txt       (2015-01-01) (0 B)
abcdedfff.txt (2015-02-01) (17 MB)
```

The controller has below code,

```
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                     .Select(Path.GetFileName).OrderBy(f => f).ToArray();

}

long fSize = 0;
var count = 0;

var fileModified = "";
string fileSize = "";
string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB" };
foreach (var filename in files)
{
   var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path + "\\" + filename);
   fSize = fileInfo.Length;
   int order = 0;
   while (fSize >= 1024 && order + 1 < sizes.Length)
   {
        order++;
        fSize = fSize / 1024;
   }

   fileSize = String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", fSize, sizes[order]);

   fileModified = fileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");

   SelectListItem file = new SelectListItem() { Value = count.ToString(), Text = filename + " ( " + fileModified + " )" + " ( " + fileSize + " )" };

   fileItems.Add(file);
   count++;
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: it depends on what kind of fond to you use in your UI. Anyway you should just prepare your `ViewData["Items"]` Collection in controller. Maby you will use `tab` symbol for this purpuse.

Comment: did you try it the way I suggested ?

Comment: Yes, fonts look good but padding is not working.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code to go into one of your Controller's methods.  I would create different classes, maybe as services, that do all of that work for you.

I think the only way to do this is to create a service that creates the space for you.

You can modify the code you already have to create the space you want, or you can create another class that does it for you.

```
public class SelectListService
{
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetData()
   {
       // Get your data       

       // create your spacing

       // return your formatted SelectList
   } 
}
```

Then in your controller you just have to...

```
var selectListService = new SelectListService();
fileItems = selectListService.GetData();
```

Then of course pass it into your View however you're already doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should modify your method if you want deservable output:

```
var maxFileNameLength = files.Max(x => x.Length);
foreach (var filename in files)
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path + "\\" + filename);
    fSize = fileInfo.Length;
    int order = 0;
    while (fSize >= 1024 && order + 1 < sizes.Length)
    {
        order++;
        fSize = fSize / 1024;
    }

    fileSize = String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", fSize, sizes[order]);

    fileModified = fileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");

    fileNameWithSpaces = filename + string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("&#160;", maxFileNameLength + 1 - filename.Length));
    SelectListItem file = new SelectListItem() { Value = count.ToString(), Text = fileNameWithSpaces + " ( " + fileModified + " )" + " ( " + fileSize + " )" };

    fileItems.Add(file);
    count++;
}
```

Ok, i check it. If you want to show your spaces in drop down you should use   rather that space. I updated the code

Comment: I tried this and it shows spacing in controller but not on view. Somehow spacing gets trimmed on the view.

Comment: @AMeh that depends on your styling. I gess you should ask css guys for it and show them you view and styles

Comment: There is no css guys, this is my dropdownlist     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FileName, ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Items"]), new Dictionary<string, object> { { "size", "15" } }). I can't add another new keyword as I already have dictionary object.

Comment: I want to add a class in dropdownlist code but I am not able to.

Comment: @AMeh you can just use `new { size = 15, color = "green"}` not new dictionary. And add all what you want

Comment: Ok. I tried that but it doesn't add padding between each listitem but to entire dropdownlist.

Comment: @AMeh that's why u say you to ask another question css guys. :) i don't even see in question your view and css situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try alignment with `String.Format` like below:

```
SelectListItem file = new SelectListItem() { Value = count.ToString(), Text = String.Format("{0,-25} ({1}) ({2})", filename, fileModified, fileSize) };
```

You can see example at [this link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/) and read more about string formatting [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=VS.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get the highest length of your filename in your collection and than use right padding and space as padding character to your filename.

Try :

```
if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                             .Select(Path.GetFileName).OrderBy(f => f).ToArray();

        }

        long fSize = 0;
        var count = 0;

        var fileModified = "";
        string fileSize = "";
        string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB" };

        int longest_file_length = files.Max(a => a.Length);



        foreach (var filename in files)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path + "\\" + filename);
            fSize = fileInfo.Length;
            int order = 0;
            while (fSize >= 1024 && order + 1 < sizes.Length)
            {
                order++;
                fSize = fSize / 1024;
            }

            fileSize = String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", fSize, sizes[order]);

            fileModified = fileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");

            string padded_file_name = filename.PadRight(longest_file_length, ' ');

            SelectListItem file = new SelectListItem() { Value = count.ToString(), Text = padded_file_name + " ( " + fileModified + " )" + " ( " + fileSize + " )" };

            fileItems.Add(file);
            count++;
        }
```

Also, you have to use monospace font so that the width of each character is same.

```
{ font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; }
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this

```
$("#selectId > option").each(function() {
var thistext=$(this).text();
var brindex=thistext.indexOf('(');
var firststring=thistext.substr(0,brindex)+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
var laststring=thistext.substr(brindex,thistext.length);
$(this).text(firsstring+laststring);
});
```

not tested but it should work